# Saving State with Bottom Navigation View

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-navigation

I'm currently writing an app that displays a list of movies. I'm using a bottom navigation view with 3 tabs: Trending, Discover, and Favorites. Each of these display a list of movies and the user can press on the movie to go to the details fragment in each one, also I'm using one nav graph.

When I scroll a bit and go to the details and use the back button, the state of the recyclerview is saved. However if I go to another tab and come back the state is not saved. After extensive research I still can't figure out the answer.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What version of the Navigation Component are you using?

Comment: nav_version = "2.3.5"

Comment: Just found this, apparently it's from 2.4.0-alpha01 and onwards lmao https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/navigation-multiple-back-stacks-6c67ba41952f

Comment: But the latest stable version is still listed as 2.3.5, should I just use the alpha version? https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation

Comment: Did "2.4.0-alpha01“ version solve your problem?

Comment: I just tried 2.4.0-alpha08 and no it did not

Comment: Nvm, it does work. Just make sure to update the nav version and the fragment version to their latest alpha versions

Answer (score 0):

I dare to assume that you do have not a dependency on the navigation fragment:

kotlin: androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version
java: androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version

Answer (score -1):

Problem caused by Navigation Component. It use replace (Fragment) instead of add (Fragment).
You can remove Navigation Component and manage Fragment by yourself, use add instead of replace fragment.

Comment: Is there no way around it?

Comment: No, this has never been the problem - `replace` already saves and restores all state [you've saved](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/saving-state). This also has nothing to do with bottom navigation and [multiple back stacks](https://link.medium.com/L2j3cu4dmjb), which *are* already supported in the Navigation Component.

Comment: Yeah I saw that blog but for some reason it's not working with me

Answer (score -1):

Found the answer: The bottom navigation now automatically handles the save state, just make sure you have the latest versions of nav and fragment. You can find the latest nav version and fragment versions here:

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment

Here is an article that explains everything you need to know

https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/navigation-multiple-back-stacks-6c67ba41952f

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.